# C++ Pthread Mutex Locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I guess I'm a little unsure of how `mutex`s work.  If a `mutex` gets locked after some conditional, will it only lock out threads that meet that same condition, or will it lock out all threads regardless until the `mutex` is unlocked?

Ex:

```
if (someBoolean)
    pthread_mutex_lock(& mut);

someFunction();

pthread_mutex_unlock(& mut);
```

Will all threads be stopped from running `someFunction();`, or just those threads that pass through the if-statement?

Comment: Mutex aren't magic. If you don't call lock, it won't lock.

Comment: And checking `someBoolean` for the lock looks suspicious and can lead to data-races and not all threads attempting to lock the mutex.

Comment: @Mat, my question is, after it is locked, will mutex only stop threads that pass the same conditional and run into the `pthread_mutex_lock(& mut);` statement?  Or will all threads just stop regardless if they hit the `pthread_mutex_lock(& mut);` statement.

Comment: As I said, no magic. If a thread doesn't call lock, it won't lock and won't block.

Comment: This is not a question about how mutexes work.It's a question about how `if` statements work. If any thread evaluates `someBoolean`, and finds it to be `true`, then it will execute the _then_ clause (i.e., `pthread_mutex_lock(&mut)`). If  `someBoolean` is `false`, then the thread won't execute the _then_ clause. The question of what state a thread finds `someBoolean` in could be tricky to answer if the variable is shared with other threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will all threads be stopped from running `someFunction();`, or just those threads that pass through the if-statement?

Only the threads for which `someBoolean` is true will obtain the lock. Therefore, only those threads will be prevented from calling `someFunction()` while someone else holds the same lock.

However, in the provided code, all threads will call `pthread_mutex_unlock` on the mutex, regardless of whether they actually locked it. For mutexes created with default parameters this constitutes [undefined behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) and must be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `pthread_mutex_lock()` in order for a thread to be locked. If you call pthread_mutex lock in thread A, but not in thread B, thread B does not get locked (and you have likely defeated the purpose of mutual exclusion in your code, as it's only useful if every thread follows the same locking protocol to protect your code).

The code in question has a few issues outlined below:

```
if (someBoolean)  //if someBoolean is shared among threads, you need to lock 
                  //access to this variable as well.
    pthread_mutex_lock(& mut);

someFunction(); //now you have some threads calling someFunction() with the lock
                //held, and some calling it without the lock held, which 
                //defeats the purpose of mutual exclusion.

pthread_mutex_unlock(& mut); //If you did not lock the *mut* above, you must not 
                             //attempt to unlock it.
```